# Error: Apex Chaining in Queue with Calls Executed in a Loop

Tags: apex

I have the following trigger:

```
trigger CaseMainTrigger_tgr on Case (before update, after insert, after update, after delete) 
{
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
           
           CaseMethods_cls.manageUpdatedCases(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
           CaseMethods_cls.createCaseComments(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
           CaseMethods_cls.updateDate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
            
            Map<Id,Schema.Case> mapOldCases = Trigger.oldMap;
            Map<Id,Schema.Case> mapNewCases = Trigger.newMap;
            for(Id iterator:mapOldCases.keySet()){
    
                if(mapOldCases.get(iterator).ComplainType__c == 'Reportes' && (mapOldCases.get(iterator).OtherComplainceStatus__c != mapNewCases.get(iterator).OtherComplainceStatus__c)){
                  SMS smsAsync = new SMS();
                          smsAsync.old = Trigger.oldMap;
                          smsAsync.news = Trigger.newMap;
                  System.enqueueJob(smsAsync);  
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a process like this:

```
public class SMS implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

    public  Map<Id,Schema.Case> old {get;set;}
    public  Map<Id,Schema.Case> news {get;set;}


    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {        
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){ 
            ValidateActivate.sendSMSNotification_Queja(old,news);
        }        
    }    
}
```

I understand that the error is due to "too many jobs in queue" and that it is a transaction error. The problem is how can I correct my code to skip or replace the process.

Comment: !Bienvenidos a SFSE! Este sitio solo esta en Ingles. Esta vez, traducimos este pregunta para tu.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much

Comment: You may find [the answer to this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/407129/is-it-guaranteed-that-first-submitted-queueable-or-batch-class-will-run-first) of help. Alternatively read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/).

Comment: @PhilW I'm sorry, I still can't find the solution :(

Comment: How would the correct code look? sorry for my bad english

Comment: The blog and Q&A both show how you can use a platform event to disconnect the trigger and the queueable to avoid hitting limits on enqueuing from a trigger.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get my hands on the code until I have the answer, in this case the lines of code that replace the trigger. It should be mentioned that I am new to Apex code. Do you have any example? Pls

Comment: @Vijaya Kapadam
Do you have any example? I am new at this :(

Answer (score 0):

> You can add up to 50 jobs to the queue with System.enqueueJob in a single transaction. In asynchronous transactions (for example, from a batch Apex job), you can add only one job to the queue with System.enqueueJob. To check how many queueable jobs have been added in one transaction, call Limits.getQueueableJobs().
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

To avoid enqueuing duplicate jobs for the same case, you can try using a set to bulkify your code in this scenario as follows. Further if the problem persists, you can consider frameworks like https://gist.github.com/tshevchuk/c6568601912843c50f97d965d4ce09e2

```
trigger CaseMainTrigger_tgr on Case (before update, after insert, after update, after delete) {
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        CaseMethods_cls.manageUpdatedCases(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
        CaseMethods_cls.createCaseComments(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
        CaseMethods_cls.updateDate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);

        Set<Id> caseIdsToSendSMS = new Set<Id>();
        for (Case updatedCase : Trigger.new) {
            Case oldCase = Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedCase.Id);
            if (oldCase.ComplainType__c == 'Reportes' && oldCase.OtherComplainceStatus__c != updatedCase.OtherComplainceStatus__c) {
                caseIdsToSendSMS.add(updatedCase.Id);
            }
        }

        if (!caseIdsToSendSMS.isEmpty()) {
            List<SMS> smsJobs = new List<SMS>();
            for (Id caseId : caseIdsToSendSMS) {
                SMS smsAsync = new SMS();
                smsAsync.old = Trigger.oldMap;
                smsAsync.news = Trigger.newMap;
                smsAsync.caseId = caseId;
                smsJobs.add(smsAsync);
            }
            for (SMS smsJob : smsJobs) {
                System.enqueueJob(smsJob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but in the second part of the Queueable, would everything be the same? :)

Comment: I replicated the code, and it generates an error in the caseId class, I omitted it, when I run the code I get an error:  


Trigger.CaseMainTrigger_tgr: line 48, column 1  
17:53:19.732 (23732331825)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE  
17:53:19.732 (23732331825)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|

--  And Code:   
 smsAsync.news = Trigger.newMap;  
                smsAsync.caseId = caseId;
                smsJobs.add(smsAsync);  
            }  
     48       for (SMS smsJob : smsJobs) {  
                System.enqueueJob(smsJob);

Comment: Trigger.CaseMainTrigger_tgr: line 48, column 1 17:53:19.732 
   (23732331825)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE 17:53:19.732  (23732331825)|LIMIT_US EDAD_PARA_NS|(predeterminado)|

Comment: @ Vijaya Kapadam ->line 48---> for (SMS smsJob : smsJobs) ----   pls help..

Comment: The error (23732331825)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE is raised when you've exceeded one of the governor limits in Apex. It's not exactly clear which limit is being exceeded based on the provided information. Also, chaining will not solve the problem if you're hitting a governor limit in a single execution context.
I feel you should consider using batch Apex.

Comment: Run this apex query in < Workbench.developerforce >  
     
    List<Case> lstCas = new List<Case>();  

    for(Case cs: [SELECT  
    ComplainType__c,Id,NumberFolio__c,Origin,OtherComplainceStatus__c FROM Case]){  
    cs.ComplainType__c = 'Aclaraciones';    
    cs.OtherComplainceStatus__c = 'En Proceso';  
    cs.recordTypeId = '01241000001IHP4AAO';  
    cs.OwnerId = '00G8Y000006eWBbUAM';  
    lstCas.add(cs);  
    }  

     if(lstCas.size() > 0){
     update lstCas;
     }